# Export mail queue to another server

Tags: import, export, centos, postfix

When I run `mailq` on SSH command line terminal, I got list of mail. However, the server does not have mail server to send those mails.

How can I export the mail queue and export it to another server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy /var/spool/mqueue directory:

```
old# tar -zpcvf mqueue.tar.gz /var/spool/mqueue
old# scp mqueue.tar.gz newserver:
new# tar -zpxvf mqueue.tar.gz -C /
```

Comment: Never used the -C flag before. I always did cd /the/directory; tar blah blah. Found it in the man page to see what it meant. Thanks for showing that!